# Why are shadows not appearing correctly on my views when running my iOS 6 app under iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have an iOS 6 app that is not yet updated to iOS 7. I am having some weird color issues with my shadows that are only appearing on iOS 7. Sometimes they look normal, and sometimes they are colored.

Normal (50% of the time the shadows appear normally on iOS 7):

[image]

Colored (50% of the time they appear this way. They should be black like above. Seems to happening with moving to and from views):

[image]
[image]

Anyone have any ideas? Here is the code I've been using for over two years now. Is there a better way to do this? Is there updated API calls that are incorrect here?

ShadowedTableView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ShadowedTableView : UITableView
{
    CAGradientLayer *originShadow;
    CAGradientLayer *topShadow;
    CAGradientLayer *bottomShadow;
}

@end
```

ShadowedTableView.m

```
#import "ShadowedTableView.h"

#define SHADOW_HEIGHT 20.0
#define SHADOW_INVERSE_HEIGHT 10.0
#define SHADOW_RATIO (SHADOW_INVERSE_HEIGHT / SHADOW_HEIGHT)

@implementation ShadowedTableView

//
// shadowAsInverse:
//
// Create a shadow layer
//
// Parameters:
//    inverse - if YES then shadow fades upwards, otherwise shadow fades downwards
//
// returns the constructed shadow layer
//
- (CAGradientLayer *)shadowAsInverse:(BOOL)inverse
{
    CAGradientLayer *newShadow = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
    CGRect newShadowFrame =
        CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width,
            inverse ? SHADOW_INVERSE_HEIGHT : SHADOW_HEIGHT);
    newShadow.frame = newShadowFrame;
    newShadow.colors =
        @[(__bridge id)(inverse ? 
                       ([self.backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0].CGColor) :
                       ([UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:inverse ? (SHADOW_INVERSE_HEIGHT / SHADOW_HEIGHT) * 0.5 : 0.5].CGColor)),
         (__bridge id)(inverse ? 
                       ([UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:inverse ? (SHADOW_INVERSE_HEIGHT / SHADOW_HEIGHT) * 0.5 : 0.5].CGColor) :
                       ([self.backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0].CGColor))];
    return newShadow;
}

//
// layoutSubviews
//
// Override to layout the shadows when cells are laid out.
//
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    //
    // Construct the origin shadow if needed
    //
    if (!originShadow)
    {
        originShadow = [self shadowAsInverse:NO];
        [self.layer insertSublayer:originShadow atIndex:0];
    }
    else if (![(self.layer.sublayers)[0] isEqual:originShadow])
    {
        [self.layer insertSublayer:originShadow atIndex:0];
    }

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];

    //
    // Stretch and place the origin shadow
    //
    CGRect originShadowFrame = originShadow.frame;
    originShadowFrame.size.width = self.frame.size.width;
    originShadowFrame.origin.y = self.contentOffset.y;
    originShadow.frame = originShadowFrame;

    [CATransaction commit];

    if (self.style == UITableViewStylePlain)
    {
        NSArray *indexPathsForVisibleRows = [self indexPathsForVisibleRows];
        if ([indexPathsForVisibleRows count] == 0)
        {
            [topShadow removeFromSuperlayer];
            topShadow = nil;
            [bottomShadow removeFromSuperlayer];
            bottomShadow = nil;
            return;
        }

        NSIndexPath *firstRow = indexPathsForVisibleRows[0];
        if ([firstRow section] == 0 && [firstRow row] == 0)
        {
            UIView *cell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:firstRow];
            if (!topShadow)
            {
                topShadow = [self shadowAsInverse:YES];
                [cell.layer insertSublayer:topShadow atIndex:0];
            }
            else if ([cell.layer.sublayers indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:topShadow] != 0)
            {
                [cell.layer insertSublayer:topShadow atIndex:0];
            }

            CGRect shadowFrame = topShadow.frame;
            shadowFrame.size.width = cell.frame.size.width;
            shadowFrame.origin.y = -SHADOW_INVERSE_HEIGHT;
            topShadow.frame = shadowFrame;
        }
        else
        {
            [topShadow removeFromSuperlayer];
            topShadow = nil;
        }

        NSIndexPath *lastRow = [indexPathsForVisibleRows lastObject];
        if ([lastRow section] == [self numberOfSections] - 1 &&
            [lastRow row] == [self numberOfRowsInSection:[lastRow section]] - 1)
        {
            UIView *cell =
            [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastRow];
            if (!bottomShadow)
            {
                bottomShadow = [self shadowAsInverse:NO];
                [cell.layer insertSublayer:bottomShadow atIndex:0];
            }
            else if ([cell.layer.sublayers indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:bottomShadow] != 0)
            {
                [cell.layer insertSublayer:bottomShadow atIndex:0];
            }

            CGRect shadowFrame = bottomShadow.frame;
            shadowFrame.size.width = cell.frame.size.width;
            shadowFrame.origin.y = cell.frame.size.height;
            bottomShadow.frame = shadowFrame;
        }
        else
        {
            [bottomShadow removeFromSuperlayer];
            bottomShadow = nil;
        }
    }
}

//
// dealloc
//
// Releases instance memory.
//


@end
```

Comment: Can't remember the details, but they did update how shadows appear on nav bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems CAGradientLayer needs RGBA of {0,0,0,0} to make a fully transparent color, which implies its blend mode changed in iOS 7. I've filed a radar for this (#15336983).

In any case, the workaround is to replace:

`([self.backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0].CGColor) :`

With:

`([UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor) :`